# how to close page in Chrome and MS Edge using javascript in first time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have two pages which are naming FATHER & CHILD PAGE.

FATHER PAGE opens CHILD PAGE using Javascript code:window.open().

Now, I would like to close FATHER PAGE from CHILD PAGE using window.opener.close().

In first time to open Chrome or MS Edge browser, CHILD PAGE CANNOT close FATHER PAGE using window.opener.close(), but it works when exists several pages in the same time and same browser instance.

How to close FATHER PAGE from CHILD PAGE when browser is opened in first time without other pages in the browser?

FATHER PAGE:
`window.open('CHILD PAGE','_blank');`

CHILD PAGE:
`window.opener.close();`

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? I use the code sample like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQu7z.png, if you open it as a first page in Edge, it can be closed using `window.close()`.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. I explain my problem again as above.

Comment: from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) _" The Window.close() method closes the current window, or the window on which it was called. This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script."_ That's all you need to know. The question is unclear because very badly stated and hard to know its details but the above I quoted is all can be said about the matter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @WeiWu May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer below? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with diegod's comment. If you open F12 devtools console tab, you'll see this warning:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.

That's the same meaning with the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close). You can't close the first parent window because it's not opened by `window.open()` script. The limitation of `window.close()` is for security and user-experience. For more detailed information, you can also refer to [this blog](https://textslashplain.com/2021/02/04/window-close-restrictions/).

So the conclusion is you just can't do it like that.